# using django-autocomplete-light outside admin view

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I've read http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#using-autocompletes-outside-the-admin

and tried to use the widget within a simple html page but it does not work and there are no JavaScript or Python errors.
Here is my code:

```
# models.py
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sample = models.OneToOneField(Sample, null=True, blank=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# views.py
class DoctorAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Doctor.objects.none()

        qs = Doctor.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

        return qs


class DocForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('name',)
        widgets = {
            'doctor': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='doc-autocomplete'),
        }

class Index(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Doctor
    form_class = DocForm
    template_name = 'index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_object(self):
        return Doctor.objects.first()


# index.html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Welcome
    <div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I want is to use their nice select2 widget to list doctor names with doctor ids as values in an autocomplete. I can do it without django-autocomplete-light, but I explicitly want to learn how to do it with their widget that looks nicer.
Can someone please guide me to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

```
class PatForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ('doctor',)
        widgets = {
            'doctor': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='doc-autocomplete'),
        }

class Index(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Patient
    form_class = PatForm
    template_name = 'index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_object(self):
        return Doctor.objects.first()
```

which produces:

[image]

if you replace ModelSelect2Multiple with ModelSelect2
then you'll get:
[image]

Comment: I am glad you solved it. I will correct the oversight at the relevant part of my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

You should override the widget of the `'doctor'` attribute int the `Patient` model instead of the `Doctor` model:

```
class DocForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ('doctor',)  # or ('__all__')
        widgets = {
            'doctor': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='doc-autocomplete'),
        }
```

Also, make sure that visiting the `reverse('doc-autocomplete')` url gives the expected results, for the logged in user, as explained in the [autocomplete tutorial.](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#use-the-view-in-a-form-widget)

---

Trying to solve a similar issue, I found out that I did not include `{{ form.media }}` in my template.

It is described in the [docs](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#using-autocompletes-outside-the-admin):

> ```
> {% block footer %}
> <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
>
> {{ form.media }}
> {% endblock %}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it still it does not load the widget; there are no javascript errors or python errors.

Comment: @max In the autocomplete-light repository, there is a [working example](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/test_project/select2_outside_admin) of this field. Is it possible that you found the solution there?

Comment: I've seen that link as it says in my post. There must be some minor thing that I'm missing.

Comment: @max I have updated my answer, regarding a misconfiguration in the ```DocForm```. I hope it helps!